# Google Apps Script WebApp onSubmit working on mozilla but not on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-apps-script

I am currently developing a WEB form, in which I want to retrieve data in a Google Sheets.

When I submit my form, a call to a handleSubmit function is supposed to launch a server-side function, allowing to retrieve the data from the form and write it into a Google Sheets.

The problem is the following:
**The script works fine on Mozilla Firefox but does not work on Google Chrome.**

In the JavaScript.html file for the "displayElectricSectionForm" method, I suspect a misinterpretation by the browser for the simple quotes when I do my :

```
html += "<form onsubmit='handleSubmit(this)'>";
```

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(request) {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
}
  
function include(filename) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function processForm(form) {
    Logger.log("Test");
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
    sheet.appendRow([form.intervenant,form.poste,form.commentaire]);
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="menu">
      <select id="menu-principal" onchange="changeMenu()">
        <option value="">-- Choisissez une section --</option>
        <option value="section-electrique">Section Electrique</option>
        <option value="section-chaufferie">Section Chaufferie</option>
        <option value="section-fluide">Section Fluide</option>
        <option value="section-pompes">Section Pompes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="formulaire"></div>
    <div id="warning"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
  <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
</html>
```

**JavaScript.html**

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      console.log('Page is loaded');
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
            alert("Hello");
        });
    
    function changeMenu() {
        var menu = document.getElementById("menu-principal");
        var formulaire = document.getElementById("formulaire");
        var warning = document.getElementById("warning");
        var value = menu.options[menu.selectedIndex].value;

        if (value == "section-electrique") {
            console.log("Section Electrique");
            afficherFormulaireSectionElectrique();
            warning.innerHTML = "";
        } else if (value == "section-chaufferie") {
            console.log("Section Chaufferie");
            formulaire.innerHTML = "<h1>Section Chaufferie</h1>";
            warning.innerHTML = "";
        } else if (value == "section-fluide") {
            console.log("Section Fluide");
            formulaire.innerHTML = "<h1>Section Fluide</h1>";
            warning.innerHTML = "";
        } else if (value == "section-pompes") {
            console.log("Section Pompes");
            formulaire.innerHTML = "<h1>Section Pompes</h1>";
            warning.innerHTML = "";
        } else {
            console.log("Choisissez une section");
            formulaire.innerHTML = "";
            warning.innerHTML = "<h1>Choisissez une section</h1>";
        }
    }

    // Créer une fonction "afficherFormulaireSectionElectrique" qui affiche le formulaire de la section électrique.
    // Dans ce formulaire, on aura un champ "Intervenant" de type "text", nécessaire pour l'envoi du formulaire.
    // On aura aussi une liste déroulante pour un champ "Poste" de type "select", avec les options suivantes : "Poste 1" jusqu'à "Poste 5".
    // On aura aussi un champ "Commentaire" de type "textarea".
    // La possibilité d'ajouter une photo de type "file".
    // UN bouton "Envoyer" de type "submit".

    function afficherFormulaireSectionElectrique(){
        var postes = ["Poste 1", "Poste 2", "Poste 3", "Poste 4", "Poste 5"];
        html = "<h1>Section Electrique</h1>";
        html += "<br> <br>";

        html += "<form onsubmit='handleSubmit(this)'>";

        html += "<label for='intervenant'>Intervenant</label>";
        html += "<input type='text' name='intervenant' id='intervenant'>";
        html += "<br> <br>";
        html += "<label for='poste'>Poste</label>";
        html += "<select name='poste' id='poste'>";
        for (var i = 0; i < postes.length; i++) {
            html += "<option value='" + postes[i] + "'>" + postes[i] + "</option>";
        }
        html += "</select>";
        html += "<br> <br>";
        html += "<label for='commentaire'>Commentaire</label>";
        html += "<textarea name='commentaire' id='commentaire'></textarea>";
        html += "<br> <br>";
        html += "<br> <br>";
        html += "<input type='submit' value='Envoyer'>";
        html += "</form>";
        document.getElementById("formulaire").innerHTML = html;
    }

    function handleSubmit(formulaire){
        console.log(formulaire);
        google.script.run.processForm(formulaire);
        alert("Formulaire envoyé");
    }

</script>
```

**Stylesheet.html**

```
<style>
    p {
      color: green;
    }
</style>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: not sure but try `<form onsubmit='handleSubmit(this.parentNode)'>`  otherwise use console.log() to debugging handleSubmit and processForm and provide more information about what's not working.  You have to learn how to debug your own code.

Comment: The above suggestion works on an onClick I don't know about an onSubmit